# Getting token from UPS.com using OAuth Error

Tags: python, authentication, http, oauth, ups

I want to get the access_token from ups.com with its developer app.

I got the result from this request.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://wwwcie.ups.com/security/v1/oauth/validate-client?client_id=testClientID&redirect_uri=https://testapplication.com'

{​​​​​
    "result": "success",
    "type": "ups_com_api",
    "LassoRedirectURL": "https://www.ups.com/lasso/signin"
}​​​​​
```

Then I was going to get code from this url

```
https://www.ups.com/lasso/signin?client_id=testClientID&redirect_uri=https://testapplication.com&response_type=code&scope=read&type=ups_com_api
```

the client id was changed my app's client_id, but the result was

```
https://www.ups.com/lasso/error?error=unauthorized_client
```

Please help me to integrate with ups

In the first step, I got the `result`, `type` and `LassoRedirectURL` from `http request`.
But the second request returns error with `302` message. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this issue couple of days ago too. I would check the following:

1. Make sure you are using the correct client_id specified in the application that you have created in the UPS developer portal.
2. Make sure the redirect_uri that you have set when you redirect the user to the login screen is exactly the same as the callback url that you have specified (letter for letter) in the application that you have created in the UPS developer portal.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have already made an integration to ups.com.