# UPS OAuth LassoReDirect URL Giving Access Denied Response

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, ups

Reference: [Getting token from UPS.com using OAuth Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76534213/getting-token-from-ups-com-using-oauth-error)

I am essentially using this document and can't get step 3 to happen in order to move on with generating a token: https://developer.ups.com/api/reference/oauth/authorization-code?loc=en_US

I get a 403 unauthorized error. I used the client id from the app (same i used for validate client call) and the callback URL (same as validate client).

Is there any secret to how to view that `lassRedirectURL`? or is it literally copy and paste into search. Just wondering if I missed a step somewhere.

I used both dev docs manually and GitHub examples to generate a matching `lassoRedirectURL` with all the parameters but still have yet to render a login page.